# Application of Tail-Recursion in OCaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, tail-recursion

I wrote this function in Ocaml but I want to write the same thing first applying tail-recursion and then `fold_left`.

```
let rec check fore list = 
    match list with 
    | [] -> [] | h :: t -> 
        if fore h 
        then h :: check fore t 
        else check fore t ;;
```

This is what I did so far. It returns a list (that is when given a list initially) that is greater than a given parameter. Example: `check (fun a -> a >= 6 )[5;4;8;9;3;9;0;2;3;4;5;6;61;2;3;4]` returns `#     - : int list = [8; 9; 9; 6; 61]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For tail-recursion, you have to add an additional parameter (an accumulator) to the `check` function. Often this is transparent by an additional internal function that's called with the initial value of the accumulator.

```
let rec check acc fore list = 
  match list with 
  | [] -> acc
  | h :: t -> 
    if fore h 
      then check (h::acc) fore t 
      else check acc fore t
```

You may need to do a `List.rev` at the end (line three), but in this case it may not be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use `List.filter` ?

```
List.filter (fun a -> a >= 6) [5;4;8;9;3;9;0;2;3;4;5;6;61;2;3;4]
```

Comment: And in fact, `filter` is tail-recursive.